# PHP exec() function throws empty array values with apache, but CLI's are fine

Tags: php, arrays, exec

I have this:

```
exec('lsblk -no "UUID" 2>&1', $result);
print_r($result);
```

in CLI mode, everything is fine, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] => d5b31fcc-ba84-47bc-ab1e-7f71178c791f
    [3] =>
    [4] => Dj0hJ3-c9C4-B1px-HIYW-DGwi-v9I9-eppfgL
    [5] => e266aff1-e6a7-444a-b9b3-2da2f9b71202
    [6] => 3fc422ac-0cde-4b54-aab1-cac10d3d5f0b
    [7] =>
)
```

But from **http**, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
)
```

Is this a bug, or a **charset** problem?

Comment: Try to do: `var_dump($result);` and look into the source code if you see anything in the browser?

Comment: it's likely to be a permission issue, where when you're logged into the console you have access to that binary, and the process of your webserver does not.

Comment: @Rizier123 still empty strings... `[0]=> string(0) ""`;
@Augwa I don't think it's about permissions, because I have the same size of the array both cases, just without values

Comment: try changing `lsblk -no "UUID"; 2>&1` also perhaps you have permissions to view the uuid with your user at the cli and the webserver does not so it just returns empty strings.

Comment: Thank you @Augwa you were right, it's about permissions about the uuid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you are logged in via the CLI the user which we'll call `root`. However when you are accessing through your browser, which goes through your webserver, it's logged in with a different user which we'll `apache`.

`root` has access to the UUID, `apache` does not.

The actual users on your specific machine may vary.